# Click outside to hide container with button

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I am using the following Angular directive to hide div elements when the user clicks or touches outside.

https://github.com/TheSharpieOne/angular-off-click

It is working as expected but when you click outside of a div on a button that toggles the div the 'angular-off-click' callback is fired to hide the container but then the toggle function attached to the button is called, reopening the div.

The 'off-click-filter' solves this by adding exceptions which use css selectors to check before the hide function is called. However this was removed as we did not want the extra bloat of css class exceptions in the html markup.

The desired function is for the toggle button not to fire its handler when you click outside of the container

**Update**
It is only a problem on touch devices where there is a 300ms delay by default. So this means that the callback is fired to hide the container then the toggle functions runs after 300ms, reopening the container. On desktop, with a mouse click, the toggle function fires first and then the callback

```js
// Angular App Code
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['offClick']);

app.controller('myAppController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.showContainer = false;
  
  $scope.toggleContainer = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.showContainer = !$scope.showContainer;
    }, 300);
    
  };
  
  $scope.hideContainer = function(scope, event, p) {
    $scope.showContainer = false;
    console.log('event: ', event);
    console.log('scope: ', scope);
    console.log(p);
  };
}]);

// Off Click Directive Code
angular.module('offClick', [])
    .directive('offClick', ['$rootScope', '$parse', function ($rootScope, $parse) {
    var id = 0;
    var listeners = {};
    // add variable to detect touch users moving..
    var touchMove = false;

    // Add event listeners to handle various events. Destop will ignore touch events
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", offClickEventHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", offClickEventHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener('click', offClickEventHandler, true);

    function targetInFilter(target, elms) {
        if (!target || !elms) return false;
        var elmsLen = elms.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < elmsLen; ++i) {
            var currentElem = elms[i];
            var containsTarget = false;
            try {
                containsTarget = currentElem.contains(target);
            } catch (e) {
                // If the node is not an Element (e.g., an SVGElement) node.contains() throws Exception in IE,
                // see https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/780874/node-contains-is-incorrect
                // In this case we use compareDocumentPosition() instead.
                if (typeof currentElem.compareDocumentPosition !== 'undefined') {
                    containsTarget = currentElem === target || Boolean(currentElem.compareDocumentPosition(target) & 16);
                }
            }

            if (containsTarget) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function offClickEventHandler(event) {
        // If event is a touchmove adjust touchMove state
        if( event.type === 'touchmove' ){
            touchMove = true;
            // And end function
            return false;
        }
        // This will always fire on the touchend after the touchmove runs...
        if( touchMove ){
            // Reset touchmove to false
            touchMove = false;
            // And end function
            return false;
        }
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        angular.forEach(listeners, function (listener, i) {
            if (!(listener.elm.contains(target) || targetInFilter(target, listener.offClickFilter))) {
                $rootScope.$evalAsync(function () {
                    listener.cb(listener.scope, {
                        $event: event
                    });
                });
            }

        });
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function ($element, attr) {
            var fn = $parse(attr.offClick);
            return function (scope, element) {
                var elmId = id++;
                var offClickFilter;
                var removeWatcher;

                offClickFilter = document.querySelectorAll(scope.$eval(attr.offClickFilter));

                if (attr.offClickIf) {
                    removeWatcher = $rootScope.$watch(function () {
                        return $parse(attr.offClickIf)(scope);
                    }, function (newVal) {
                        if (newVal) {
                            on();
                        } else if (!newVal) {
                            off();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    on();
                }

                attr.$observe('offClickFilter', function (value) {
                    offClickFilter = document.querySelectorAll(scope.$eval(value));
                });

                scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                    off();
                    if (removeWatcher) {
                        removeWatcher();
                    }
                    element = null;
                });

                function on() {
                    listeners[elmId] = {
                        elm: element[0],
                        cb: fn,
                        scope: scope,
                        offClickFilter: offClickFilter
                    };
                }

                function off() {
                    listeners[elmId] = null;
                    delete listeners[elmId];
                }
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.container {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    
    
  </head>

  <body data-ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div data-ng-controller="myAppController">
      
      <button data-ng-click="toggleContainer()">Toggle Container</button>
      
      <div class="container" data-ng-show="showContainer" data-off-click="hideContainer()" data-off-click-if="showContainer">
        This is the container
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/hibovu

Comment: Please create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/) so we could see the problem.

Comment: I can't see the snippet (SO snippet, so we can see it in action). Also, if you have update for the question, please edit your question and add it (not in comment). Let me know when you do it.

Comment: I have added a 300ms delay to the toggleContainer function to simulate the touch delay

Comment: I have added a clear problem statement, please can you re-review.

Comment: I'm confused.. Is there a problem with this code? Because in my test (on mobile device) I can't see a problem.

Comment: open the container and then toggle it again, it will reopen

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you click on the button the both of the functions are firing:

1. `hideContainer` from the directive.
2. `toggleContainer` from the click event (that showing the `div` again).

**The solution**

Add [`event.stopPropagation();`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) before you evaluate the `hide` callback.

How do you do this?

1. Pass the event to the function `data-off-click="hideContainer($event)"`.
2. Add the `$event` param in the definition of the `hideContainer` function in the `$scope` like this: `$scope.hideContainer = function($event)`

**And the full code:**

```js
// Angular App Code
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['offClick']);

app.controller('myAppController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.showContainer = false;

  $scope.toggleContainer = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.showContainer = !$scope.showContainer;
    }, 300);
  };

  $scope.hideContainer = function($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.showContainer = false;  
    });
  };
}]);

// Off Click Directive Code
angular.module('offClick', [])
.directive('offClick', ['$rootScope', '$parse', function ($rootScope, $parse) {
  var id = 0;
  var listeners = {};
  // add variable to detect touch users moving..
  var touchMove = false;

  // Add event listeners to handle various events. Destop will ignore touch events
  document.addEventListener("touchmove", offClickEventHandler, true);
  document.addEventListener("touchend", offClickEventHandler, true);
  document.addEventListener('click', offClickEventHandler, true);

  function targetInFilter(target, elms) {
    if (!target || !elms) return false;
    var elmsLen = elms.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < elmsLen; ++i) {
      var currentElem = elms[i];
      var containsTarget = false;
      try {
        containsTarget = currentElem.contains(target);
      } catch (e) {
        // If the node is not an Element (e.g., an SVGElement) node.contains() throws Exception in IE,
        // see https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/780874/node-contains-is-incorrect
        // In this case we use compareDocumentPosition() instead.
        if (typeof currentElem.compareDocumentPosition !== 'undefined') {
          containsTarget = currentElem === target || Boolean(currentElem.compareDocumentPosition(target) & 16);
        }
      }

      if (containsTarget) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  function offClickEventHandler(event) {
    // If event is a touchmove adjust touchMove state
    if( event.type === 'touchmove' ){
      touchMove = true;
      // And end function
      return false;
    }
    // This will always fire on the touchend after the touchmove runs...
    if( touchMove ){
      // Reset touchmove to false
      touchMove = false;
      // And end function
      return false;
    }
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    angular.forEach(listeners, function (listener, i) {
      if (!(listener.elm.contains(target) || targetInFilter(target, listener.offClickFilter))) {
        //$rootScope.$evalAsync(function () {
        listener.cb(listener.scope, {
          $event: event
        });
        //});
      }
    });
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function ($element, attr) {
      var fn = $parse(attr.offClick);
      return function (scope, element) {
        var elmId = id++;
        var offClickFilter;
        var removeWatcher;

        offClickFilter = document.querySelectorAll(scope.$eval(attr.offClickFilter));

        if (attr.offClickIf) {
          removeWatcher = $rootScope.$watch(function () {
            return $parse(attr.offClickIf)(scope);
          }, function (newVal) {
            if (newVal) {
              on();
            } else if (!newVal) {
              off();
            }
          });
        } else {
          on();
        }

        attr.$observe('offClickFilter', function (value) {
          offClickFilter = document.querySelectorAll(scope.$eval(value));
        });

        scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
          off();
          if (removeWatcher) {
            removeWatcher();
          }
          element = null;
        });

        function on() {
          listeners[elmId] = {
            elm: element[0],
            cb: fn,
            scope: scope,
            offClickFilter: offClickFilter
          };
        }

        function off() {
          listeners[elmId] = null;
          delete listeners[elmId];
        }
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

```css
.container {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body data-ng-app="myApp">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div data-ng-controller="myAppController">
      <button data-ng-click="toggleContainer()">Toggle Container</button>
      <div class="container" data-ng-show="showContainer" data-off-click="hideContainer($event)" data-off-click-if="showContainer">
        This is the container
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/hibovu/3/edit?html,css,js

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this was one of the first solutions I tried and it will not work as I need the event to propagate. Stopping the propagation will stop any subsequent event from firing. e.g. opening a different dropdown

Comment: OK, I just was updated my answer. Let me know if it's working for you as you expected.

Comment: user5453221 Is that the answer you looked for?